# Why can't I use a where clause on both tables in a LINQ Group Join?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Here's what I want to do:

```
Dim queryX = From m In db.Master
             Where m.Field = value
             Group Join d In db.Detail
             On m.Id Equals d.MasterId Into Group
             Where d.Field = value
```

In English, I want to join the master and detail tables, specifying conditions on each.  But this causes the following compiler error:

"Name 'd' is either not declared or not in the current scope."

It works if I put this same condition in functional form:

```
Group Join d In db.Detail.Where(Function(x) x.Field = value)
```

but I think this is more typing, harder to understand, and introduces that irritating dummy variable.  I *really* would prefer to use the query comprehension syntax.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need a group join here and not just a join like this

try

```
Dim queryX = From m In db.Master
             Where m.Field = value
             Join d In db.Detail
             On m.Id Equals d.MasterId 
             Where d.Field = value;
```

?

Comment: Right, I was unclear about that.  It has to be a group join because the detail item may not exist, so I need a left join and not an inner join.  Wait, all of a sudden I'm not entirely clear on the difference between Join and Group Join.

Comment: @Joshua for left join, you can call `db.Detail.DefaultIfEmpty()` for join vs group join, you might be better off looking them up on msdn.

Comment: Okay, I read up on this (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531340.aspx) and found this statement: "The Join clause...is equivalent to an INNER JOIN in SQL....You can use the Group Join clause to combine collections into a single hierarchical collection. This is like a LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL."  Are you saying that you CAN use a regular Join statement when you need a left join, if you use DefaultIfEmpty?

Comment: @Joshua check out this blog post on left outer join using `DefaultIfEmpty()` http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/

Comment: This looks helpful, and it also looks like MSDN is either incomplete or wrong.  But it sounds like your answer will work for me, so thanks.